# How do I fix my while loop?

Tags: python

So I'm coding the game RISK for practice, but I've encountered a problem, so here I am.
Basically, during

```
while numAttacking>0:
    print("numAttacking=",numAttacking)
    if defensiveForce>0:
        print("defensiveForce=",defensiveForce)
        for x in range(numAttacking):
            defenseRate=random.randint(1,12)
            attackRate=random.randint(1,12)
            if defenseRate>=attackRate:
                REGION_DATA[attacker]['TROOP_COUNT']=REGION_DATA[attacker]['TROOP_COUNT']-1
                print("Lost one unit")
            else:
                REGION_DATA[defender]['TROOP_COUNT']=REGION_DATA[defender]['TROOP_COUNT']-1
                print("Killed one unit")
```

my code stalls and gets stuck in the while loop. I hope it is clear what I want, but put simply I want it to function so that the user inputs how many troops they are attacking with similar to how RISK works in real life, then the code loops until either the attacker or defender runs out of units to attack or defend with, respectively.

```
import random

regions=    ['ALASKA','NORTHWEST_TERRITORY','GREENLAND','ALBERTA','ONTARIO','EASTERN_CANADA','WESTERN_USA','EASTERN_USA','CENTRAL_AMERICA']

REGION_DATA={'ALASKA'                :{'OWNER':'Player 1',   'TROOP_COUNT':3,   'Bordering':['NORTHWEST_TERRITORY','ALBERTA']},
         'NORTHWEST_TERRITORY'   :{'OWNER':'Player 1',   'TROOP_COUNT':4,   'Bordering':['ALASKA','ALBERTA','ONTARIO','GREENLAND']},
         'GREENLAND'             :{'OWNER':'Player 1',   'TROOP_COUNT':4,   'Bordering':['NORTHWEST_TERRITORY','ONTARIO','EASTERN_CANADA']},
         'ALBERTA'               :{'OWNER':'Player 1',   'TROOP_COUNT':7,   'Bordering':['ALASKA','NORTHWEST_TERRITORY','ONTARIO','WESTERN_USA']},
         'ONTARIO'               :{'OWNER':'Player 1',   'TROOP_COUNT':7,   'Bordering':['NORTHWEST_TERRITORY','GREENLAND','EASTERN_CANADA','EASTERN_USA','WESTERN_USA','ALBERTA']},
         'EASTERN_CANADA'        :{'OWNER':'Player 2',   'TROOP_COUNT':6,   'Bordering':['GREENLAND','ONTARIO','EASTERN_USA']},
         'WESTERN_USA'           :{'OWNER':'Player 2',   'TROOP_COUNT':7,   'Bordering':['ALBERTA','ONTARIO','EASTERN_USA','CENTRAL_AMERICA']},
         'EASTERN_USA'           :{'OWNER':'Player 2',   'TROOP_COUNT':7,   'Bordering':['ONTARIO','WESTERN_USA','EASTERN_CANADA','CENTRAL_AMERICA']},
         'CENTRAL_AMERICA'       :{'OWNER':'Player 2',   'TROOP_COUNT':5,   'Bordering':['WESTERN_USA','EASTERN_USA']}
        }
def invade(attacker,defender):
#print("16")
attacker=attacker.upper().replace(" ","_")
defender=defender.upper().replace(" ","_")
#print(attacker,defender)
defensiveForce=REGION_DATA[defender]['TROOP_COUNT']
attackForce=REGION_DATA[attacker]['TROOP_COUNT']
#print(attackForce,defensiveForce)
#print("22")
print("You have ",attackForce," troops available to attack with.")
print("How many troops are you attacking with?")
numAttacking=int(raw_input())
if numAttacking>attackForce:
    print "You don't have that many troops available!"+'\n'+"You only have",attackForce," troops available."+'\n'+"How many troops will you use?"
    numAttacking=raw_input()
while numAttacking>0:
    print("numAttacking=",numAttacking)
    if defensiveForce>0:
        print("defensiveForce=",defensiveForce)
        for x in range(numAttacking):
            defenseRate=random.randint(1,12)
            attackRate=random.randint(1,12)
            if defenseRate>=attackRate:
                REGION_DATA[attacker]['TROOP_COUNT']=REGION_DATA[attacker]['TROOP_COUNT']-1
                print("Lost one unit")
            else:
                REGION_DATA[defender]['TROOP_COUNT']=REGION_DATA[defender]['TROOP_COUNT']-1
                print("Killed one unit")
    else:
        REGION_DATA[defender]['OWNER']=REGION_DATA[attacker]['OWNER']
        print("45")
        break  

print(REGION_DATA[attacker]['TROOP_COUNT'])
```

My problem is that

```
invade('ontario','eastern usa')
```

outputs

```
('You have ', 7, ' troops available to attack with.')
How many troops are you attacking with?
```

(I will fix the parenthesis and quotation marks later, I do know what is causing that, but I'm too lazy right now.)

to which I respond

```
3
```

the code then gets stuck outputting a bunch of the print commands but never exits the while loop. How do I fix this?

Comment: `raw_input` returns a string, and comparing strings to integers doesn't produce a meaningful result. If you want to take an integer input, call `int` on the string to get an integer.

Comment: that isn't the problem, I'm using the raw_input to give numAttacking a value, then I'm comparing that to another int, and if you're talking about another section of the code I can assure you that it works fine. The only error was the one answered below.

Comment: Ctrl-f `numAttacking=raw_input()` and you'll see the section I'm talking about. It may or may not be causing the problem you're asking about, but it's definitely causing problems.

Comment: I haven't had any problems with it, but I guess redundancy never hurt, so are you suggesting that I use `numAttacking=int(raw_inut())`?

Comment: Yes. You'll have problems with it if you try to attack with more troops than you have.

Comment: I just tested that in canopy and it works fine. I'll post the input and output below.                                                 `invade('Ontario','Eastern USA')
You have  6  troops available to attack with.
How many troops are you attacking with?

8
You don't have that many troops available!
You only have 6  troops available.
How many troops will you use?

9
You don't have that many troops available!
You only have 6  troops available.
How many troops will you use?

0
You killed  0  units and lost  0  units in your failed invasion.`

Comment: It's likely your posted code and the code you're testing are different in some way, then. Perhaps there's an extra `int` call somewhere, or perhaps the troop counts are strings. It's hard to tell.

Comment: Oh wow I feel dumb (I'm noticing a pattern here unfortunately!). I had already changed it to `numAttacking=int(raw_input())`. I guess you were right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top of your code, you've set defensiveCount. However, you don't update that amount inside of your while loop. Its never going to reach the "else" section of your if/else trial, therefore its going to try to keep attacking and killing troops, even into the negatives. numAttacking isn't going to change either, so it won't auto break out of the while loop.

EDIT:

What you may think is happening is that you're setting defensiveCount to the amount in the list. However, that's only setting it to that number at defensiveCount's definition, that number does not change unless explicitly told to.

Comment: ...you know those moments when you feel really dumb?

Comment: This is one of them. Thanks for the help!